# Copy file difference between 2 folders and a third folder using Windows commands

Tags: powershell, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I have seen the topic of copying the difference of two folders to a third folder on this site and others yet I cannot find a single suggested solution that works for me. I'd like to use Robocopy, Xcopy or powershell.

The folders will be called **current**, **Changed**, and **moved**.
**Current** is the current production folder. It contains a variety of files but the files I want to copy and move are all .txt files.

I already figured out how to use Robocopy using the /XO switch to copy the files with a difference or which are new from **current** to **changed**.  I want to overwrite the files from current in changed on a daily basis as step 1.

However for step 2 I need to then copy only what was newly copied to **changed** to the third folder **moved** which will ultimately be zipped and FTP'd to a different server. The **moved** folder should contain only the delta files. I'm aware of a /MOV command but I couldn't figure out how to use it for my purposes. Any suggestions how to script this?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing a manual version control. Why not use something like Git? I'm asking because you specifically mention you only want the Deltas.

Comment: I've heard of Git but not that familiar. I'll do some research on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\current"
SET "destdir=U:\changed"
SET "targetdir=U:\moved"
xcopy /L /y /d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" "%destdir%\" |findstr /v /e "File(s)"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'xcopy /L /y /d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" "%destdir%\" ^|findstr /v /e "File(s)"'
 ) DO (
 ECHO %%a
 COPY /y "%%a" "%targetdir%\"
 COPY /y "%%a" "%destdir%\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir`, `destdir` and `targetdir` to suit your circumstances (these are simply standard names that I use).

Append `>nul` to the `COPY` commands to to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

The `echo` of the filename is obviously optional.

Process the output of `xcopy /L /D /Y` line-by-line to `%%a`. The `/L` option generates a list but does not actually copy the files. `/Y` forces overwrite without prompt, and coupled with `/L` ensures the `xcopy` completes without requiring user action (responding to the `overwrite?` prompt). The `/D` specifies "new or newer" files should be copied.

The `findstr` filter looks for lines `/v` **not** `/e` ending with the string `File(s)` - which is the last line of the `xcopy /L` output.

`%%a` thus has the name of each file that *should* be copied, so the two `copy` commands copy the new files to each of the two required destination directories.

Comment: How might I save the results to a text file in the moved folder?

Comment: `echo %%a>>"%targetdir%\textfilename.txt"` within the loop